# use SignalR inside Service Stack REST API service

Tags: web, webserver, signalr, servicestack

Is it possible to use SignalR inside of a service stack project? We currently are using service stack for our REST web API. We have been pleased overall with its architecture, flexibility, etc. Now we are exploring ways to communicate back with our calling clients using event-driven or push techniques (vs polling for status). I should note that we are currently hosting our API in a windows service, using the AppHostHttpListenerBase (vs hosting inside IIS).

Is it possible to configure a dedicated route that would be passed to SignalR Hub somehow, so these two could live side by side? e.g. `http://localhost:8000/api/live/jobs/jobid` would hit the SignalR code, but `http://localhost:8000/api/jobs/jobid` would route to the current DTO based service stack code.

PS - We would like to continue hosting in self host mode, as we like the flexibility of porting to Mono and running on Linux (vs being tied to IIS).

Comment: I've just encountered this problem - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This blog post describes how to use SignalR with a ServiceStack backend: 
[SignalR, Filters and ServiceStack](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/03/signalr-filters-and-servicestack/)

To summarize, you have to change the ServiceStack Request behavior to Bufferered,

```
public HelloAppHost()
    : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly)
{
    PreRequestFilters.Add((req,res) => req.UseBufferedStream = true);
}
```

Then you can add [IncomingHub], [OutgoingHub] attributes to the service methods, like Get() and Post(), etc.

As for OWIN support in ServiceStack, don't hold your breath. [This thread](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/4851342-owin-compatible-servicestack) shows the opinion of the primary maintainer that there is not a strong case for adding support at this time.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR provides a [self host](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host) option built using OWIN.

I notice that Service Stack will [soon also have an OWIN hosted implementation](http://dhickey.ie/post/2012/10/11/ServiceStack-OWIN-support-sneak-peek.aspx) in case you are unable to add SignalR in place.

You could then use something like [Firefly](https://github.com/FireflyServer/firefly) to easily host both parts of your app without tying yourself to any one server implementation.

Here is the self host start up code for reference:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;

namespace SignalR.Hosting.Self.Samples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";

            using (WebApplication.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapHubs();
        }
    }

    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```